# Working with DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have some problems understanding the DateTimeOffset...

I am trying to create a simple-trigger for a Quartz-Job.
There exists a triggerbuilder with which one can create such a trigger like this:

```
var triggerbuilder =
                TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity(triggerName, ConstantDefinitions.InternalDefinitions.AdhocJobGroup)
                .StartAt(new DateTimeOffset(scheduledTime));
```

The scheduledTime is a DateTime. Let's say it is `new DateTime(2014, 10, 15, 14, 0, 0);`

I live in a city which lies in the Central European Time Zone (UTC+01:00).

When I print

```
var dto = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2014, 10, 15, 14, 0, 0));
Console.WriteLine(dto);
```

I get the following result:

> 15.10.2014 14:00:00 +02:00

What does the +02:00 exactly mean? And why is it +2:00 and not +01:00?
Does that mean, that my trigger will be started at 16:00 instead of 14:00?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure? What is your `dto.OffSet` property returns? Maybe it is because of daylight saving time?

Comment: Note: when DST is active, your city *isn't* using CET. It's using CEST, which is a different time zone offset and gets a different name. The only countries using CET at this time are, perhaps surprisingly based on the name, not in Europe.

Comment: Your city uses (European) summer time until the last Sunday of October. October 15 is therefore in the "summer" part of the year. So CEST (+02:00), not CET (+01:00).

Comment: @hvd Yes, are you referring to [WAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Africa_Time) without summer time, like in Nigeria and many other countries?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I was referring to Algeria and Tunisia, which supposedly call their time zone CET yet do not use DST. Nigeria uses the same time zone offset, but calls it differently (WAT, as you say). But, actually, I'm not sure whether what I found is correct. Perhaps an inhabitant of one of those countries or another reliable source can clear it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`15.10.2014 14:00:00 +02:00`  is a datetimeoffset (datetime + timezone) representing 2pm local time in a timezone of +2 UTC

this is equivalent to `15.10.2014 12:00:00` in UTC

With regard to why is it `+02:00` rather than `+01:00`, is daylight savings active?

[Converting Between DateTime and DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546101(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You are correct, the DateTimeOffset of my 2014-10-15 16:00 date gets saved as ticks to the database and when I create a new DateTime with these ticks, it says its 2014-10-15 14:00... do you know how I can make it save as 16:00?

Comment: I'd need to see your code. Are we talking about C# or TSQL?. Also, consider asking a separate question.

Comment: Quartz.NET saves times always as UTC in database. This is why it will have the value of 14:00 and *implicit* time zone of UTC, you need to use TimeZoneInfo to convert it to time zone you're in. Or just call ToLocalTime().