# Quatz.Net GetNextFireTime() returning the "wrong timezone"

Tags: datetime, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, datetimeoffset

I am currently working on a project in which I am using the Quartz Scheduler.
I've been working on a feature that displays different details about jobs that are currently active, using the following method.

```
public IEnumerable<ActiveScheduleJob> GetAllActiveScheduls()
    {
        var activeScheduls = new List<ActiveScheduleJob>();

        try
        {
            IList<string> jobGroups = scheduler.GetJobGroupNames();
            // IList<string> triggerGroups = scheduler.GetTriggerGroupNames();

            ActiveScheduleJob ASJ;

            foreach (string group in jobGroups)
            {
                var groupMatcher = GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupContains(group);
                var jobKeys = scheduler.GetJobKeys(groupMatcher);
                foreach (var jobKey in jobKeys)
                {
                    var detail = scheduler.GetJobDetail(jobKey);
                    var triggers = scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
                    foreach (ITrigger trigger in triggers)
                    {
                        ASJ = new ActiveScheduleJob();
                        ASJ.Group = group;
                        ASJ.Name = jobKey.Name;
                        ASJ.Description = detail.Description;
                        ASJ.TriggerKeyName = trigger.Key.Name;
                        ASJ.TriggerKeyGroup = trigger.Key.Group;
                        ASJ.TriggerGetTypeName = trigger.GetType().Name;
                        ASJ.TriggerState = scheduler.GetTriggerState(trigger.Key);
                        ASJ.NextFireTime = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc();
                        if (ASJ.NextFireTime.HasValue)
                        {
                            ASJ.NextFireTimeString = ASJ.NextFireTime.Value.LocalDateTime.ToString();
                        }

                        ASJ.PreviousFireTime = trigger.GetPreviousFireTimeUtc();
                        if (ASJ.PreviousFireTime.HasValue)
                        {
                            ASJ.PreviousFireTimeString = ASJ.PreviousFireTime.Value.LocalDateTime.ToString();
                        }
                        ASJ.FullJobString = $"Trigger Name: {ASJ.TriggerKeyName} | Trigger Group: {ASJ.TriggerKeyGroup} | Trigger State: {ASJ.TriggerState} | Trigger Get Type: {ASJ.TriggerGetTypeName} | Job Name: {ASJ.Name} | Job Group: {ASJ.Group} | Next Fire Time: {ASJ.NextFireTimeString} | Previous Fire Time: {ASJ.PreviousFireTimeString} | Description: {ASJ.Description}";
                        activeScheduls.Add(ASJ);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logging.WriteLog(1, "JobScheduler", "GetAllActiveScheduls", "Hent alle aktive job+triggers", $"EXCEPTION MESSAGE: {ex.Message} | EXCEPTION INNER: {ex.InnerException}", LogType.Exception, "");
        }
        return activeScheduls;
    }
```

The method in it self works just fine, my problems lies in the fact that the GetNextFireTime() method, gives it in UTC which is an hour behind my GMT+1 / UTC+1.

When it displays: **10-01-2018 07:00:00 +00:00**

It should display: **10-01-2018 08:00:00 +01:00**

I've looked at the following link: [Working With DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382559/working-with-datetimeoffset)

and tried to work with what [Marko Lahma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111604/marko-lahma) mentioned could work in converting the DateTimeOffset. But I've run into a wall where I can't convert it, because GetNextFireTime() returns a DataTimeOffset? and what I've tried, can't convert something thats Nullable. So I am abit stumped in what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the `DateTimeOffset` to a local DateTimeOffset and that to a DateTime.

```
var nextFireDateTime = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc()?.ToLocalTime().DateTime;
```

Please note that `nextFireDateTime` could be null.

Comment: I knew there was another way of doing it, this did the trick. Thanks for the help